# Hibernate mapping inheritance

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, mapping, entity

I have a class ClassA mapped to TableA. I also have a mapping for it and it has an entity-name of EntityA.

Now, I need to create another mapping named EntityATwo between ClassA for TableA, but slightly different.

Although I could copy-paste the mapping of EntityA to EntityATwo, it would be very difficult to maintain that.

Thus, my question is, how do I create the mapping for EntityATwo wherein I declare there only what is different between EntityATwo and EntityA, while the rest of the mappings are derived from EntityA.

Thanks,
Franz

Comment: +1 for precise question, and good interactions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a way to do that directly. But with your permission, I might elaborate.

---

In our code, we usually like to have **one java class map to one semantic** (we prefer to work with compile-checked class than unchecked Strings). Therefore, instead of mapping twice the class to the table with different entity names, we would **map two classes**.
We would have :

- ClassA as the common superclass, with most mapping that is common. It is declared (in hbm.xml) with all this mapping.
- ClassA1 extends ClassA, provide its unique mapping (and java code if needed, otherwise it could be empty). It inherits the common mapping from ClassA.
- ClassA2 also

You don't have duplication anymore. And you gain something on semantics.

---

Another possibility is to **use annotations on the java class, only for the common mapping**. In Hibernate, Annotations can be overriden (or completed) by xml mappings. So I guess you could **override only the relevant part in xml**, and you would have no duplication.

Comment: Please feel free to elaborate some more :-) 

I guess it's ok for me to have two classes mapped to the same table. But still, how do I say that EntityATwo map is practically the same as that of EntityA map with some slight differences.

Thanks

Comment: @Franz I edited to focus on your comment. Is it clearer? Hibernate site is down, so I can't provide a link.

Comment: Ok, so you have ClassA1 & ClassA2 both extending ClassA from the java side. ClassA maps to to TableA (for example). Also, ClassA1 & ClassA2 maps to TableA. 

But how do you exactly specify that ClassA1 & ClassA2 inherit the common mapping from ClassA?

Thanks

Comment: I believe Hibernate understands this already. Because of the inheritance in your classes (classes that are declared to Hibernate), it should understand this. I'm doing this routinely using Annotation technology (which I suggest if you can by the way), but I believe it should be the same for xml. Both mappings get translated to the same meta-data. (Note: we are using two-sides reference between some entities with annotations and other in xml, and it works fine!).